# Can't bind data after $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't understand why my creators array isn't bind.
I try to wrap $scope.setCreators() into $scope.$apply I got INPROG error, and wrapped into $timeout it doesn't work ither.
Here's the code :

JS :

```
$scope.creators = [
    { firstName: 'test', middleName: 'peter', lastName: 'po'}
];

$scope.$on('pageChanged', function(e, data){
    if( data.cat !== 'creator' ) return;
        $scope.getCreators( data.page );
});

$scope.setCreators = function( creators ){
    $scope.creators = creators;
    console.log( $scope.creators );
};

$scope.getCreators = function( page ){
    var query = {
        offset: page * $scope.offset,
        limit: $scope.offset
    };

    $http.post(baseURL+'/creators', query).success(function(data){
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.setCreators( data.data.results );
        }, 0);
    });
};
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="CreatorCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="creator in creators">
    {{creator.firstName}}
    {{creator.middleName}}
    {{creator.lastName}}
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have anything in `data.data.results`? Also, add the `error` callback to `$http.post` to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to use `$timeout` instead of `$setTimeout`? (I don't find the latter documented anywhere right now)

Comment: data.data.results is not empty.
@doldt I made a mistake in the post it's $timeout not $setTimeout. But it doesn't work.

Comment: in progress errors when you attempt to trigger a digest cycle whilst already inside of one. Can we see the code that prompted that error?

Comment: no need to wrap a $http success in an apply/digest/timeout wrapper. It should work.. Does it show the test creator before loading of the real creators? If it does, there is something wrong with the `data.data.results`

Comment: Why are you using a post method to retrieve data btw?

Comment: Yes the test creator works fine. Just seems the datas can't be bind. @skubski I use post to send parameters

Comment: @DanPantry here is the error http://i.imgur.com/Bfy58ZU.png

Comment: And does the test creator gets removed after loading of the data? I believe the only reason this could not be working, is because `data.data.results` is not an array. Could you post a screenshot of the `console.log( $scope.creators );` inside the `$scope.setCreators` function..

Comment: @PierreDuc There is the screenshot of the log inside `$scope.setCreators` http://i.imgur.com/ibeVs6R.png

Comment: Does the test creator disappear after loading?

Comment: No he is not changing. Looks like I don't set the right var.

Comment: Is it possible there is a problem with the ng-view ?

Comment: Eventhough this is unrelated to your problem you should take it into consideration to use the http methods the way they should be used.  A [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is designed for this operation. POST is for unsafe and non idempotent operations.

Comment: @skubski Request changed ;) Ty for the advice

Comment: You can see the whole code here https://github.com/poillic/marvelApi/tree/master/server I have the refresh issue for the creators list and the comics list.

Comment: The bug occurs only when I call the `$scope.getCreators` in the `$scope.$on` any idea ?